# Loading a local JSON file with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to load the contents of a JSON file in a JS file and write it to my main HTML file, but am unsure how to approach it.

What I've done so far is as follows:

index.html:

```
<p>
    Name: <span id="dogName1"></span><br>
    Breed: <span id="dogBreed1"></span><br>
    Age: <span id="dogAge1"></span><br>
    Image: <span id="dogImage1"></span><br>
</p>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name":"pets",
  "Dogs":[
    {
      "Name":"Oliveander",
      "Breed":"German Shepherd",
      "Age":3,
      "Image":"images/GermanShepherd.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Ripley",
      "Breed":"Golden Retriever",
      "Age":5,
      "Image":"images/GoldenRetriever.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Remi",
      "Breed":"Siberian Husky",
      "Age":2,
      "Image":"images/SiberianHusky.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

main.js:

```
$.getJSON( "data/package.json", function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data received, name is " + json.name);
});
```

All I've been able to understand so far is that the code I have in my JS file is the method in which I load the JSON file, but I'm unsure how to proceed

Comment: Hi @Varehen. Do you get info in the console?

Comment: It is important to know that you cannot load the file, using directory access. Instead you must load it as URL address. Open YOUR_SITE/data/package.json in URL and see if the data appears first, before proceed on jQuery part. Then modify data/package.json to have leading slash eg: /data/package.json

Comment: @fwyh that is correct for Chrome but not Firefox

Comment: @Katie.Sun i did, it came up as "JSON Data received, name is Pets"

Comment: Well, in getJSON function you can iterate json.Dogs as @Dhaval Pankhaniya has shown, but instead to console you can use your jQuery with $('#dogName1').html(jsonDogs[i].Name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the jQuery `append()` method. You use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON( "data/package.json", function( json ) {
        console.log( "JSON Data received, name is " + json.name);
        for(let i in json.Dogs){
            var dog = json.Dogs[i];
            $("#dogTable").append(getDogMarkup(dog));
        }
    });
});

function getDogMarkup(dog){
    return 'Name: <span class="dogName">' + dog.Name + '</span><br>' +
    'Breed: <span class="dogBreed">' + dog.Breed + '</span><br>'+ 
    'Age: <span id="dogAge1">' + dog.Age + '</span><br>'+ 
    'Image: <span id="dogImage1">//image html here</span><br><br>';
}
```

What you'll need to do is make something of an anchor point in your HTML that you can fill with the data you want, like so: `<div id="dogTable"></div>`

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! i should be able to sort it out from here! :D

Comment: @Varehen glad to hear it! If my answer works for you please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply iterate json data like below

```js
var jsonData = {
  "name":"pets",
  "Dogs":[
    {
      "Name":"Oliveander",
      "Breed":"German Shepherd",
      "Age":3,
      "Image":"images/GermanShepherd.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Ripley",
      "Breed":"Golden Retriever",
      "Age":5,
      "Image":"images/GoldenRetriever.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Remi",
      "Breed":"Siberian Husky",
      "Age":2,
      "Image":"images/SiberianHusky.jpg"
    }
  ]
  }
  for(var i=0;i<jsonData.Dogs.length;i++){
    console.log("Name : "+ jsonData.Dogs[i].Name)
    console.log("Age : "+ jsonData.Dogs[i].Age)
    console.log("Bread : "+ jsonData.Dogs[i].Bread)
    console.log("------------------------------------")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He is trying to write to the HTML, not the console.